# Decode JPEG to char*

Tags: c++, opencv

Please help to solve this small problem:

I try to decode incoming jpg data by OPENCV:

```
cv::Mat video_frame = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(buffer), -1);

char* drawingData=??????;
```

I can draw "drawingData" on the screen mannually if it is RGB 24 bits format.

So the problem is how could I get the the drawingData from this video_frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
char* data = (char *)image->imageData;
```